# Paypal sandbox IPN message not revieved

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I Integrate my web application with Paypal sandbox IPN, I send a notify_url and payment completed successfully as Paypal said

> you just completed your payment.
>   Your transaction ID for this payment is: ******.
>   We'll send a confirmation email to *****.

But notify url i send not working the contents function and It doesn't exists in Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history

What can i do for debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal keeps a history of your IPN and you can request that they resend any given IPN

Log into your PayPal account and you can visit the [IPN History Page](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history), where you can see the full list. Clicking on a given IPN request will tell you the URL it was sent to and the time, as well as the full string of POST variables. You can also have that request reset if needed.